# How to Mask the images with rotation in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdk

I am making an app which gives texture effects to the image with the concept of masking. User can also rotate the image at any angle.

My problem is that when I rotate the image the masking disappears here is the code that I am using for masking and rotation.

```
-(IBAction)rotateImageView:(id)sender
{
    if (isRotated)
    {
        resultimg.image=rotateimage;
    }
    if([resultimg.image imageOrientation] == UIImageOrientationUp)
    {
        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img  CGImage]  scale:img.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];

        rotateimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[resultimg.image CGImage]  scale:resultimg.image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    }
    else if ([resultimg.image imageOrientation] == UIImageOrientationRight)
    {
        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img  CGImage]  scale:img.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];

        rotateimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[resultimg.image CGImage]  scale:resultimg.image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
    }
    else if ([resultimg.image imageOrientation] == UIImageOrientationDown)
    {
        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img  CGImage]  scale:img.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];

        rotateimage= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[resultimg.image CGImage]  scale:resultimg.image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft]; 
    }
    else if ([resultimg.image imageOrientation] == UIImageOrientationLeft)
    {
        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img  CGImage]  scale:img.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        rotateimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[resultimg.image CGImage]  scale:resultimg.image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];  
    }

    resultimg.image=rotateimage;
}
```

Where image refers to original image, resultimg.image refers to the imageview that contains image with effects that is masked image.

And for masking I am using this code.

```
-(void)masking
{
    int m=k ;

    UIImage *textureImage;

    textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imagearray2 objectAtIndex:m]];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sizeR, YES, textureImage.scale);
    [textureImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sizeR.width, sizeR.height)];

    UIImage *bottomImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    upperImage= img;

    //upperImage =rotateimage;

    CGSize newSize = sizeR ;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sizeR.width, sizeR.height)];
    [upperImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, sizeR.width, sizeR.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.7];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    resultimg.image=newImage;
}
```

Comment: Put formated code and text. At least remove unwanted space.